# Wordpress: migrated site redirect to old home page. Happens only with the home page

Tags: wordpress, migration

I just migrated a Wordpress site from one domain (domain-old.com) to another (domain-new.com). The problem is that the homepage: **domain-new.com** is redirected to: **domain-old.com**

It **only happens with the home page.** The other pages like: `domain-new.com/some-page`, `domain-new.com/other-page`, etc. work fine.

What I did so far after migration of files and database:

- In wp-config.php I changed `define('DB_NAME',...)` , `define('DB_USER', '...')`, `define('DB_PASSWORD', '...')` and `define('DB_HOST', '...')` to connect to the database
- In the database: click on the wp_options table and modify the values of the site_url and home column with your new URL.
- updated permalinks: Settings -> Permalinks
- In wp-config.php I added: `define('WP_HOME','http://domain-new.com');` and `define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain-new.com');`
- In my child theme in functions.php I added: `update_option ( 'siteurl', 'http://domain-new.com' );` and `update_option ( 'home', 'http://domain-new.com' );`
- I installed the plugin [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) and run a Search and Replace for all tables in the database to search `domain-old.com` and  replace them with `domain-new.com`

I don't know what else can I do. I think the problem is in the htaccess, but in there I just have this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have no cache plugin enabled.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I was in this exact situation and this question and the solution helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your cache, or flushing your dns.

If it is working fine in a different browser/incognito mode etc, then it will simply be a cache issue, in which case just wait it out for it to clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some updates to database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'http://olddomain.ru', 'http://newdomain.ru') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://olddomain.ru','http://newdomain.ru');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://olddomain.ru', 'http://newdomain.ru');
```

You don't need do anything to move your wordpress instead of this changes.